Linearization of Linear Fractional Constraint
Can this constraint be converted to a set of linear constraints:
$$
z_j \leq \sum_{c \in C} \left( \mu_c  \cdot x_{cj} + (1 - \mu_c)  \cdot \frac{L_{cj} \cdot (1+\beta_{cj})}{\sum_{k \in S} L_{ck} \cdot(1+\beta_{ck})} \right) \forall j \in S
$$
Where,
$x_{cj} \in \{0,1\}, \beta_{cj} \in [0,1]$, $z_j \geq 0$ are decision variables and $\mu_c \in [0,1] \forall c \in C$, and $L_{cj} \in [0,1] \forall c \in C, j \in S$ are input parameters, s.t. $\sum_{c \in C} \mu_c = 1$ and $\sum_{j \in S} L_{cj} = 1 \forall c \in C$
PS: I wonder if this is a valid approach. Multiply and divide the fractional term by a new decision variable $s_c \geq 0$ such that:
$$
z_j \leq \sum_{c \in C} \left( \mu_c  \cdot x_{cj} + (1 - \mu_c)  \cdot L_{cj} \cdot (1+\beta_{cj}).s_c \right) \forall j \in S \\
\sum_{k \in S} L_{ck}  \cdot (1+\beta_{ck}) \cdot s_c = 1 \forall c \in C \\
s_c \geq 0
$$

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The constraint contains a linear fractional term. I want to convert this constraint to maybe 2 or more constraints so that they are all linear.

$z_j$ is a continuous decision variable s.t., $z_j \geq 0$ and $L_{ck} \in [0,1]$ s.t., $\sum_k L_{ck} = 1$.

@AvalpreetSingh Could you disambiguate the order of arithmetic operations in the right-hand side of your expression by parentheses? (Following up on your comment to my answer)

@RobPratt yes,  and Konstantin Sidorov done

@AvalpreetSingh In that case, I think the approach you have suggested is valid: you introduce $s_c$ such that any feasible solution has $s_c = \frac{1}{\sum_k L_{ck} (1 + \beta_{ck})}$, observe that the only nonlinearities stem from $\beta_{ck} s_k$ terms, and then proceed with the standard technique for them. Do you want me to update the answer, or can you now linearize this on your own?

What you proposed is the Charnes-Cooper transformation.  You don't need to do any further linearization other than to simply replace each product $\beta_{cj} s_c$ with a new nonnegative variable $t_{cj}$.  After solving the resulting MILP, you can then recover the original variables $\beta_{cj}$ as $t_{cj}/s_c$.

Thanks @RobPratt and  Konstantin Sidorov.

@Konstantin Sidorov please go ahead... this will complete the discussion.

@AvalpreetSingh, done:)

Following up on the discussion we have shared in the comment section with Avalpreeet Singh (the question author) and Rob Pratt, I propose to linearize your constraint following the plan outlined below:

Remove the sum-of-fractions term by introducing the variables $s_c=\frac{1}{\sum_{j\in S} L_{cj}(1+\beta_{cj})}.$
Encode terms of the form $s_c \beta_{cj} = \frac{1}{\sum_{j\in S} L_{cj}(1+\beta_{cj})}$ with new variables $t_{cj}$ and remove the $\beta$-variables from the constraint, relying on the fact that any feasible solution of the original set of constraints can be recovered uniquely as $\beta_{cj}=\frac{t_{cj}}{s_c}$.

Removing the sums of fractions
We start by introducing new variables $s_c \in [1/2, 1]$ and constraining them in a way that enforces the identity $$s_c=\frac{1}{\sum_{j\in S} L_{cj}(1+\beta_{cj})} \tag{1} $$ in any feasible solution; introducing the non-zero lower bound may seem excessive now but will prove vital for the second step of the plan.
This leaves us with the following two constraint systems: $$\begin{align} 
\forall j \in S &: z_j \le \sum_{c \in C} \Big\{ \mu_c x_{cj} + (1 - \mu_c)L_{cj}s_c(1 + \beta_{cj}) \Big\}, \tag{2} \\
\forall c \in C &: \sum_{j \in S} L_{cj} s_c (1 +\beta_{cj}) = 1. \tag{3}
\end{align}$$
This is a valid rewrite of the original system in the sense that $(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{\beta}, \boldsymbol{z})$ is a feasible solution of the original system if and only if $(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{\beta}, \boldsymbol{z}, \boldsymbol{s})$ is a feasible solution of (2) and (3) with $\boldsymbol{s}$ being given by identity (1). Indeed, if $(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{\beta}, \boldsymbol{z})$ is feasible, then such a choice of $\boldsymbol{s}$ will satisfy both the range constraints (see the next paragraph) and the new constraints (2) and (3), as substituting (1) into them will transform them to the original constraint and to a $1=1$ identity respectively. Conversely, if $(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{\beta}, \boldsymbol{z})$ is not feasible, then no choice of $\boldsymbol{c}$ can satisfy (2) and (3), because otherwise, you could recover the feasible solution to the original constraints.
The only hole in this reasoning is the satisfaction of range constraint $1/2 \le s_c \le 1$; to close it, we have to verify that the definition (1) always satisfies it under the question assumptions. This is equivalent to the double inequality $$1 \le \sum_{j\in S} L_{cj}(1+\beta_{cj}) \le 2,$$ which we can simplify further by using the $\sum_j L_{cj} = 1$ identity: $$0 \le \sum_{j\in S} L_{cj}\beta_{cj} \le 1.$$ The lower bound is true because we are summing the products of nonnegative variables, whereas the upper bound is true because $\beta_{cj} = 1$ and, once again, the $\sum_j L_{cj} = 1$ identity.
Encoding the product terms
Next, we introduce new variables $t_{cj}\ge 0$ and use these variables to replace all the non-linear terms in (2) and (3) as follows: $$\begin{align} 
\forall j \in S &: z_j \le \sum_{c \in C} \Big\{ \mu_c x_{cj} + (1 - \mu_c)L_{cj}(s_c + t_{cj}) \Big\}, \tag{2$'$} \\
\forall c \in C &: s_c + \sum_{j \in S} L_{cj} t_{cj} = 1. \tag{3$'$}
\end{align}$$
This is a valid rewrite of (2) and (3) in the sense that $(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{\beta}, \boldsymbol{z}, \boldsymbol{s})$ is a feasible solution of (2) and (3) if and only if $(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{t}, \boldsymbol{z}, \boldsymbol{s})$ is a feasible solution of (2') and (3') with $t_{cj}=s_c \beta_{cj}$ for all $j\in S, c \in C$. Checking this in both directions amounts to substituting either $\beta_{cj} = s_c / t_{cj}$ or $t_{cj} = s_c \beta_{cj}$ and simplifying the resulting expressions to get either (2') and (3') from (2) and (3) or the other way round. This transformation is well-defined due to the $s_c \ge 1/2$ bound, allowing you to divide by $s_c$ this way.
Putting the reasoning above together, you get that (2) and (3) are equivalent to (1), and (2') and (3') are equivalent to (2) and (3), which transitively gives you a linear system of constraints that is equivalent to the original one.
